# Capybara - select an option based on Partial text

Tags: capybara, partial

I have an option value on page as  - RMSOrg (Initializing)

Initializing as a text goes away after some validations. In automation I am just passing RMSOrg. How do I select the option based on partial text?

This syntax does not work

find('#organisation_id').find("option[contains(.,'#{@orgname}')]").select_option

@orgname has value RMSOrg. Initializing as a text goes away after a while so cannot time when it goes away so I have to select by partial text.. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
find('#organisation_id').select('RMSOrg', exact: false)
```

Should do what you want, and if #organisation_id is the actual select element you can just do

```
select('RMSOrg', from: 'organisation_id', exact: false)
```